# Several nearly identical if statements need to be shortened

Tags: php

So I've got this code...

code:

```
    if(empty($day0[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$day0[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day0[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$day0[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$day0[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day0[2]." - ".@$day0[3]."</td>";
        }
    }

    if(empty($day1[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$day1[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day1[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$day1[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$day1[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day1[2]." - ".@$day1[3]."</td>";
        }
    }

    if(empty($day2[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$day2[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day2[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$day2[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$day2[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day2[2]." - ".@$day2[3]."</td>";
        }
    }

    if(empty($day3[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$day3[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day3[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$day3[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$day3[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day3[2]." - ".@$day3[3]."</td>";
        }
    }

    if(empty($day4[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$day4[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day4[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$day4[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$day4[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day4[2]." - ".@$day4[3]."</td>";
        }
    }

    if(empty($day5[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$day5[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day5[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$day5[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$day5[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day5[2]." - ".@$day5[3]."</td>";
        }
    }

    if(empty($day6[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$day6[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day6[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$day6[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$day6[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day6[2]." - ".@$day6[3]."</td>";
        }
    }
```

Where day 0-6 equals Sunday through Saturday, and the array numbers attached to each one equals a different variable in a multi-dim array.

That is several if statements that are all exactly the same except the variable name inside of each one. I haven't been able to find a way to make this shorter, so I thought I would post here to try and see if anyone has any ideas on how I can combine this into shorter lines of code. I'm all about my code looking neater and functioning better, and I think this could teach a lot of people good ways to shorten their code down a bit.

Comment: This may be more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Create a function where you pass the variables instead.

Comment: @Raidri Ah, you are totally right! I completely forgot about that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[MagnusEriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson) suggested making a function, I think this is the best way to do it.

From 69 lines of code to 18 lines of code.

```
function displayTime($day1,$day2,$day3) {
    if(empty($day2)) {
        return "<td>{$day1}<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($day1,"Absent") == 0) {
            return "<td>{$day1}<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        }
        return "<td>{$day1}<br>Time: {$day2} - {$day3}</td>";
    }
}

for ($x = 0; $x <= 6; $x++) {
    echo displayTime(${"day$x"}[1],${"day$x"}[2],${"day$x"}[3]);
}
```

Comment: The only thing I would change is to have the function return the string instead of echoing it. But that's just me, hating when functions echoes stuff without you having any control over where and when.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Normally I would agree but either way it will only be echoing 1 thing.

Comment: I would like you to make this DRYer with a `for` loop calling the function.   ...pretty please.

Comment: @mickmackusa Done :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 7 months later revisiting this answer, I totally agree with you and have made changes as such.

Answer (score 2):

First merge all array of $day[n] in to $finalArray

```
foreach($finalArray as $key=>$value){
    if(empty($value[2])) {
        echo "<td>".$value[1]."<br></td>";
    } else {
        if(strcmp($value[1],"Absent") == 0) {
            echo "<td>".$value[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>".$value[1]."<br>Time: ".@$value[2]." - ".@$value[3]."</td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code.

```
    $array=array($day0,$day1,$day2,$day3); 

    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
        if(empty($day.$i[2])) {
            echo "<td>".$day.$i[1]."<br></td>";
        } else {
            if(strcmp($day.$i[1],"Absent") == 0) {
                echo "<td>".$day.$i[1]."<br>Time: N/A</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td>".$day.$i[1]."<br>Time: ".@$day.$i[2]." - ".@$day.$i[3]."</td>";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this actually work?  Regardless, this answer needs some explanation to be complete.